# i want the div tag repeat using ng-repat

Tags: html, angularjs

```js
<script>
  var app = angular.module("myapp", []); 
     app.controller('test',function($scope){
   $scope.my="hi";
   $scope.myimag=["Feature-Category1.png","Feature-Category2.png","Feature-Category3.png","Feature-Category1.png","Feature-Category1.png"];

    });
  </script>
```

```html
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="test">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" ng-repeat="x in myimag">
<a href="#"><img alt="" ng-src="{{x}}"></a>
 </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
```

i want to repeat the items in the myimg but it not working it get errors why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing module, controller and again use **`$scope`** variable instead of var,

```
  $scope.myimg=["img.png","img1.png","img2.png"];
```

**DEMO**

```js
var testApp= angular.module('test',[])
angular.module('test').controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.myimg=["altair7.jpg","altair6.jpg"];
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="testCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="x in myimg ">
      <a href="#"><img ng-src="{{x}}"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @banuprakash check the demo

Comment: use ng-src instead of src

Answer (score 0):

Three problems With your code :

1. You haven't defined an angular module.
2. You haven't defined a controller for that view.
3. In order to acheive two way data binding , you need to define your variables with **$scope** instead of defining it as 'var'

Update your code as shown below :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myimg=["img.png","img1.png","img2.png"];
});
```

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="x in myimg ">
    <a href="#"><img ng-src="{{x}}"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```